# How to update label text on second kivy screen

Tags: kivy

I have got a small kivy app with two screens. I am trying to update a label on the second from the first

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

# Declare both screens
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def SetText(self):
      text='Total='+str(17*21)
      StrategyScreen().SetText(text)

class StrategyScreen(Screen):
    labelText = StringProperty()
    labelText='My label'
    print 'start'

    def SetText(self, text):
      print 'a', self.labelText
      self.labelText=text
      print 'b', self.labelText

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Create the screen manager
        screenManager = ScreenManager()
        screenManager.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
        screenManager.add_widget(StrategyScreen(name='strategy'))
        return screenManager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

with kv file:

```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: 'Goto strategy'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'strategy'
        Button:
            text: 'Set text'
            on_press: root.SetText()

<StrategyScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: root.labelText
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'
```

Judging from 'start' there is only one instance of StrategyScreen and SetText is being called correctly, but the label still displays the old text.

Can anyone please help

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding OOP here. The class StrategyScreen has no __init__ and so how does it know what 'self' is? I'm soooo confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in `SetText` method of your `MainScreen` class. Calling `StrategyScreen().SetText(text)` creates new temporary object of type `StrategyScreen()`, calls method `SetText` on it and then discards it since is no longer needed. To get an existing screen use `self.manager.get_screen()` method:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def SetText(self):
        text = 'Total=' + str(17*21)
        self.manager.get_screen('strategy').SetText(text)
```

Instead of calling `StrategyScreen` method you can just change its property directly:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: 'Goto strategy'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'strategy'
        Button:
            text: 'Set text'
            on_press: root.SetText()

<StrategyScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: root.labelText
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'
''')

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def SetText(self):
        text = 'Total=' + str(17*21)
        self.manager.get_screen('strategy').labelText = text

class StrategyScreen(Screen):
    labelText = StringProperty('My label')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Create the screen manager
        screenManager = ScreenManager()
        screenManager.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
        screenManager.add_widget(StrategyScreen(name='strategy'))
        return screenManager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you Nykakin. I couldn't see my way around it but you've helpd me do it

Comment: @Nykakin, thanks for the thorough answer.  I'll add that I found the labelText datatype set to a StringProperty() was especially helpful.  I think Kivy needs this to be an object, instead of a string, for example, to work.